# SQL - Replacing an is null integer with a varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, null

I am trying to replace a column with a new `varchar` string if there is null values in it in a select statement:

```
(personid + ISNULL(personid, 'no person'))
```

I'm not trying to update it, only show the value as 'no person' in the query result.

But I am getting an error saying:

> the conversion failed when converting the varchar value to a data type int.

How do I get past this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
(personid+ISNULL(personid,'no person'))
```

With this:

```
(ISNULL(CAST(personid as varchar(31)),'no person')) AS personId
```

Comment: Sorry, I just checked now and the field name is actually stored as 'NULL' instead of not showing anything. How would I go about converting that to something else in the query result? Thanks !

Comment: But this still worked as the personid field is INT so I had to change it anyway! Thanks a lot bro!

Comment: I'm confused as to where you say they are storing 'NULL'.  If the personId field is INT, they can't be storing the string 'NULL' in it.   If you mean the column header doesn't have a name, that can be fixed with a alias.   See my edited answer above.